# Need help loading KML - this is my first Google Maps project

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

This is my first Google Maps js project.  I have used the Google Earth for some time.
I have a page that has a drop list of KML URLs.  Initially the map needs to center on a selected point.  This works find. After the droplist selection it needs to load a KML file.  The KML file I use is the same as used in Google Earth.  I am viewing with chrome and see no errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Test Google Maps Project\</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var map;
     function initialize() 
     {
      var csmap = new google.maps.LatLng(40.8471706333333,-72.6395958166667);
      var mapOptions = 
      {
        zoom: 15,
        center: csmap 
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     function fetchKmlFromOption() {
      //Load the selected KML
      var kmlUrlBox = document.getElementById('KMLSelector');
      var kmlUrl = kmlUrlBox.value;
      if (kmlUrl !='Clear') {
        var geoLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl);
        geoLayer.setMap(map);
      }
     }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; border: 0;"  bgcolor="#E6CFCF">
    <CENTER>
    <div id="main">
     <H1>Test Google Maps - KML Loader</H1>
     <H2>Google Maps API Demo</H2>
     Select KML option :
      <select id='KMLSelector' onchange='fetchKmlFromOption()'>
       <option value='Clear'>Clear loaded KML</option>
       <option value='THIS-IS-FIRST-KML-URL'>Fetch First KML</option>
       <option value='THIS-IS-SECOND-KML-URL'>Fetch Second KML</option>
       <option value='THIS-IS-THIRD-KML-URL'>Fetch Third KML</option>
      </select>
      <BR>
      <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    </CENTER>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to provide a public URL (or URLs) that exhibit the problem for us to tell what is going on.  Another option would be to check the returned status ([KmlStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus)) of the KmlLayer to see if it loaded successfully.

Comment: The page is located at : 'https://www.mebcs.com/gabreskiairportGM/'

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues

1. (minor)you call initialize 2 times:

   ```
   <body onload="initialize()" ....>
   ```

   and

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   ```

   remove 1 call.
2. the url contains illegal characters(spaces), encode the url via `encodeURI`
3. each time you select a layer from the list you create a new layer, but there is a limit for the number of layers
4. 2 of the 3 layers are a bit large, there is a limit of 3MB for the filesize(the size of these layers is 3MB). The documentation isn't clear whether  the size-limit applies to a single layer or all layers, but as it appears it's related to all layers. So when you load a 3MB-layer you can't load further layers. Possible solution: always load only  a single layer:

   ```
   function fetchKmlFromOption() {
     //use a single layer
      if(!map.get('kml')){
        map.set('kml',new google.maps.KmlLayer);
      }
      kml=map.get('kml');
     //Load the selected KML
     var kmlUrlBox = document.getElementById('KMLSelector'),
         kmlUrl = kmlUrlBox.value,
         kml=map.get('kml');

     if (kmlUrl !='Clear'){
       kml.setValues({'url':encodeURI(kmlUrl),map:map});

     }else{
       kml.setMap(null);
     }
    }
   ```
5. Although the layers may be loaded you will see nothing when you use this style for your placemarks:

   ```
    <Style id="hideLabel">
     <LabelStyle>
      <scale>0</scale>
     </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
   ```